# Category and Subcategory display (Parent/Child)

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table which contains parent Sports whose Parent ID is always 0 and child Sports which have ParentID as SportID of the Parent Sport. Few sample records are given below.

SportID           SportName              ParentID
1                 Cricket                0
2                 T20 Cricket            1
3                 50 Over Cricket        1
4                 Test Cricket           1
5                 Football               0
6                 World cup football     5
7                 Euro Cup Football      5
8                 Volleyball             0
9                 Beach Volleyball       8
10                Ground Volleyball      8

```
I need to write a Stored procedure so that the output should be like the     following.
```

SportID           SportName
1                 Cricket
2                  - T20 Cricket
3                  - 50 Over Cricket
4                  - Test Cricket
5                  Football
6                    -World cup football
7                    - Euro cup Football
8                  Volleyball
9                    - Beach Volleyball
10                   - Ground Volleyball

Note: The records are in random order in my table. I really need someone's help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursive CTE can do this - down to any depth:

#### EDIT: added proper sorting and added one element third level "Test Cricket2" below ID 4

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(SportID INT,SportName VARCHAR(100),ParentID INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,'Cricket',0)
,(2,'T20 Cricket',1)
,(3,'50 Over Cricket',1)
,(4,'Test Cricket',1)
,(5,'Football',0)
,(6,'World cup football',5)
,(7,'Euro Cup Football',5)
,(11,'Test Cricket2',4)
,(8,'Volleyball',0)
,(9,'Beach Volleyball',8)
,(10,'Ground Volleyball',8);

WITH RecursiveCTE AS
(
    SELECT CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS Inx, SportID,SportName,ParentID,1 AS Level
    FROM @tbl 
    WHERE ParentID=0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT rc.Inx + '.' +CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) AS VARCHAR(10)),tbl.SportID,CAST(REPLICATE('--',rc.Level) + tbl.SportName AS VARCHAR(100)),tbl.ParentID,rc.Level +1 
    FROM RecursiveCTE AS rc
    INNER JOIN @tbl AS tbl ON tbl.ParentID=rc.SportID
)
SELECT * FROM RecursiveCTE
ORDER BY Inx,Level
```

The result

```
+-------+---------+----------------------+----------+-------+
| Inx   | SportID | SportName            | ParentID | Level |
+-------+---------+----------------------+----------+-------+
| 1     | 1       | Cricket              | 0        | 1     |
+-------+---------+----------------------+----------+-------+
| 1.1   | 2       | --T20 Cricket        | 1        | 2     |
+-------+---------+----------------------+----------+-------+
| 1.2   | 3       | --50 Over Cricket    | 1        | 2     |
+-------+---------+----------------------+----------+-------+
| 1.3   | 4       | --Test Cricket       | 1        | 2     |
+-------+---------+----------------------+----------+-------+
| 1.3.1 | 11      | ----Test Cricket2    | 4        | 3     |
+-------+---------+----------------------+----------+-------+
| 2     | 5       | Football             | 0        | 1     |
+-------+---------+----------------------+----------+-------+
| 2.1   | 6       | --World cup football | 5        | 2     |
+-------+---------+----------------------+----------+-------+
| 2.2   | 7       | --Euro Cup Football  | 5        | 2     |
+-------+---------+----------------------+----------+-------+
| 3     | 8       | Volleyball           | 0        | 1     |
+-------+---------+----------------------+----------+-------+
| 3.1   | 9       | --Beach Volleyball   | 8        | 2     |
+-------+---------+----------------------+----------+-------+
| 3.2   | 10      | --Ground Volleyball  | 8        | 2     |
+-------+---------+----------------------+----------+-------+
```